# Quick Question about inclusion-Exclusion principle

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

[image]

|S| indicates the cardinality of a set S (which may be considered as the number of elements of the set, if the set is finite).

I just learnt about this principle when trying to solve a problem and found myself messily applying this principle.

I don't understand why the cardinality is included in the principle. Does it not hold if you take all the | | out of the statement and replace with ( ), and then is that not a stronger principle and true?

Comment: What then have you in mind for the meaning of $(A_i)$?

Comment: A set, eg. for n = 2 $A_{1}=\left\{ 3,4,5\right\} $ , $A_{2}=\left\{ 2,4,5\right\} $, the formula without the cardinality gives you $\left\{2, 3,4,5\right\}$= A1 union A2?

Comment: But then what e.g. is $\sum_{i=1}^nA_i$? A summation of sets?... In your example you make it $\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ but that set we already see at the LHS, so we get something like $\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i-\cdots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be shown that: $$1_{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i}=\sum_{i=1}^n1_{A_i}-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}1_{A_i\cap A_j}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}1_{A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n}\tag1$$

where $1_B$ denotes the indicator function of set $B$.

Taking integrals wrt some measure $\mu$ on both sides we arrive at:$$\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\mu(A_i\cap A_j)+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\mu(A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n)$$

The inclusion/exclusion rule concerning cardinality shows up if  $\mu$ is prescribed by $A\mapsto|A|$.

Care is needed because on the RHS we also meet subtraction. Under the condition that every $A_i$ is finite nothing can go wrong in the cardinality case.

Comment: right ok, this is very basic but I think this is what I don't get so this is not true: $A\cup B=A+B-A\cap B$, but $ |A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ is

Comment: It is true that $1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B-1_{A\cap B}$. Sets cannot be added or subtracted just like that. If you insist on doing that, then you first need to make  rules for it.

Comment: right I think that's it then, so the indicator function works, which is more general, than the inclusion/exclusion, but you cant add and subtract sets. It just seems to me, that all the formula tells you is that they have the same number of elements, not that they are identical elements.

Comment: Yep, that's what I am saying.

Comment: @thanks, A+B, when they are sets doesn't make sense.

Comment: It only makes sense if the addition has been defined on some way. $A+B=A\Delta B$ is a candidate, but in that case $1_{A+B}=1_A+1_B-1_A1_B\neq1_A+1_B$.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. So I can see with the above formula, if I take the expectation I get the probability version of the exclusion/inclusion principle. I don't get quite what I am summing to get the cardinality version, am I summing over all the possible elements in U Ai ?

Comment: Integrating wrt any suitable measure $\mu$ you get $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)-\cdots$. Now observe that also the function $A\mapsto|A|$ is a measure. So that special case gives you the cardinality version. Taking a probability measure gives you the probability version.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to define addition and subtraction on "multisets", so if $A=\{2,3,5\}$ and $B=\{5,7,8\}$ then $A+B=\{2,3,5,5,7,8\}$ and $A+B-(A\cap B) = \{2,3,5,7,8\}$. Defining things in this way might have both advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: That is cool, Thanks for pointing that out. Then it would be possible to have the formula, without cardinality.