# Express $P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D)$ in terms of probabilities of intersections

Tags: probability

Find $P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D)$.

What would the formula be?

---

My attempt:

$P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D) - P(AB) - P(AC) - P(BC) - P(ABC) - P(ABD) - P(BAC) - P(BAD) - P(DAB) - P(DAC) + P(ABCD)$

right?

Comment: You seem to be striving for the inclusion-exclusion principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle This isn't quite it....

Comment: Did you mean to write $\Pr(A \cup B \cup C \cup D)$ on the left-hand side?

Comment: Yeah whoops, nf

Comment: Have a look at $(1)$ in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2831219/75923) for $n=4$ and integrate wrt $P$ on both sides. You are making several mistakes in your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right general concept, but not exactly right. You're missing some terms and some signs are wrong. It's as follows:

$$P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D)\\ 
- P(AB) - P(AC) - P(AD) - P(BC) - P(BD) - P(CD)\\
+ P(ABC) + P(ABD) + P(ACD) + P(BCD) \\
- P(ABCD)$$

System: Add probabilities of ${4\choose 1} = 4$ single sets, subtract probabilities of intersections of ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ pairs of sets, add probabilities of intersections of ${4 \choose 3} = 4$ triples of sets, and subtract probability of ${4 \choose 4} = 1$ intersection of all four sets.

You can do something similar with three sets and show all the parts easily in a Venn Diagram. Not so easy to do a simple and clear Venn diagram for four sets in 2-D.